# Javascript array of numbers

Tags: javascript

How can I modify an array of numbers to not have space between ',' and number,
for example [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  I don't want spaces , I want change it to [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] please help me!

Comment: arrays don't have spaces; they are not strings. What do you *actually* want to do? *print* the array differently?

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(`[${arr.toString()}]`); // "[1,2,3]"
```

This will convert your array to string without spaces.